# Printing Excel sheets with COM interface

Tags: python, excel, pywin32, win32com

I've programatically made a bunch of Excel sheets with xlwt in python. It's all gone fine, but now I need to convert them all to pdf. I've been trying to do this with pywin32 and the com interface. I can get somewhat close by going like this:

```
import win32com.client
o = win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
o.Visible = 1
wb = o.Workbooks.Open('foo.xls')
ws = wb.Worksheets[1]
ws.printout()
```

But unfortunately when I do this it pops up the adobe printer screen asking me for the path I want to save the pdf to, and if I have to enter that in or click ok for every page it defeats the purpose of doing it programatically. Is there any way I can enter this path in the python code rather than manually? Is there a better way of converting each of these sheets in each of these workbooks to pdf?
Thanks a lot,
Alex

Comment: Unfortunately that's the default behavior of the Adobe PDF printer driver.

Comment: I found that the PrintOut() is case sensitive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using the `PrintOut` method, use `ExportAsFixedFormat`. You can specify the pdf format and supply a file name. Try this:

```
ws.ExportAsFixedFormat(0, 'c:\users\alex\foo.pdf')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do a save as PDF or print to PDF.  That should bypass your print driver issues.

Comment: hmm ok, sorry how do I do that?